# I mixed sql and sqli commands..but this gives errors..what is the correct code?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

There's some error in this piece of code..can someone care to correct me?

```
$user_list=mysqli_query("SELECT 'id','username', FROM 'users' ");
    while($run_user=mysqli_fetch_array($user_list)){
        $user=$run_user['id'];
        $username=$run_user['username'];
        echo "<p><a href='send.php?user=$user'>$username</a></p>";
        }
```

From comments made below -

> mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\wamp\www\2\send.php on line 44

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: *They're not getting any Sam* @JayBlanchard ;-) and tutorials?! doubt it.

Comment: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\wamp\www\2\send.php on line 44

Comment: Google mysqli tutorials.

Comment: this is a terrible question. Please go over proper tutorials before posting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummm, see your `SELECT` query once, it's full of errors like below

1. don't quote column names and table names else DB engine will think it as string literal rather a column.
2. there is a extra `,` before `FROM` clause in your query.

Correct one should be

```
SELECT `id`,`username` FROM `users`
```

Comment: i jus tried what u told me..still the same

Comment: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\wamp\www\2\send.php on line 44..this is the error

Comment: Hmm, someone downvoted ... not sure why though? Any idea???

Comment: ....was not me. but reason could be that db connection isn't in the answer? who knows if OP even has those setup too.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, LOL I have no idea about PHP brother ... saw the mistakes in query so answered :)

Comment: however Rahul, the question itself is a real "can of worms". OP is posting all these other error messages and didn't bother reading and understanding tutorials. We are not a school after all ;-) I gave an upvote for the initial question.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Yes,  indeed it is. I feel like deleting my answer :)

Comment: the choice is yours amigo ;-) best to just run away lol

Comment: @Fred-ii-, you are playing politics with me now ... :). I know that's what you want me to do ... LOL :) nice talking friend. Cheers.

Comment: If I had put in an answer for the question and be faced with all of this, I would have no hesitated to delete my answer. We can't save them all.... *cheers* ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Just replace `quotes` with `backtick` also mysqli_query need connection in your first parameter

```
 $user_list=mysqli_query(PASS_YOUR_CONNECTION_VARIABLE,"SELECT `id`,`username` FROM `users`");
```

Comment: not debugged..still the same..

Comment: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\wamp\www\2\send.php on line 44

Comment: Ok, but what about the `,` before FROM???

Comment: yeah i removed it..still the same

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\wamp\www\2\send.php on line 45..these two errors

Comment: have you pass your connection variable as your first parameter

Comment: @sathwik mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given.......... your query failed and you need to find out why that is. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()`. --- `$connection` being the connection variable example you are using to connect with.

Comment: it was error in connection variable...thanks anyway @Saty